# How I can make AWK for all match in multiple lines

Tags: bash, awk

Hi I have issue with AWK I need parse some text and I don't know how I can parse recursively.

I have this:

```
awk '/^tags: /{p=$2} /^[0-9]* /{v=$2} /^$/{print ""p" "v""}'
```

but that parse only first compliance, I need all match.

input (sensorId can be more than 2):

```
name: temperature
tags: sensorId=1
time                last   value
----                ----   -----
1593531518973361030 40.125 40.125

name: temperature
tags: sensorId=2
time                last   value
----                ----   -----
1593531338178622316 -0.062 -0.062
```

I'd like output:

```
1 40.125
2 -0.062
```

or

```
sensorId=1 40.125
sensorId=2 -0.062
```

I use [mawk](/questions/tagged/mawk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you only print when there's a blank line. There's no blank line after the last occurrence, just the end of the file. You can match that with `END`.

```
awk '/^tags: /{p=$2} /^[0-9]* /{v=$2} /^$/{print p, v} END {print p, v}'
```

Another option is to print both values immediately when you match the second line.

```
awk '/^tags: /{p=$2} /^[0-9]* /{print p, $2}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
awk '
    /sensorId=/{printf "%s ", $2}  # print $2 without newline if match /sensorId/
    length($1) > 10 {print $2}     # if length > 10, print $2
' file
```

I assume `$1`: `1593531518973361030` is at least 10 chars long. Adapt the min length if needed.

### Output

```
sensorId=1 40.125
sensorId=2 -0.062
```

Comment: ```s/awk/nawk/```

Comment: awk: not an option: --version

Comment: I have raspberry 
awk: not an option: --version

Comment: Please, clean comments

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written with shown samples.

```
awk '
/^tags/{
  found=1
  val=$NF
  next
}
found && /^[0-9]+/{
  print val,$2
  val=found=""
}
' Input_file
```

***Explanation:***

Checking if a line starting with tags then setting found to 1 then creating val and setting it to current line's last field value. Using next function to skip all further statements from here.

Then checking condition if found is SET and line starts with 19 digits then print value of val and 2nd field here. Nulify val here.

Comment: I dont know why but it doesn't return anythink

Comment: @ŠtěpánKukla, not sure if your awk is of old version, could you please check my edited solution now and lemme know then.

Answer (score 1):

As your data looks well structured, this could work:

```
$ awk -v RS="" '{print $4,$NF}' file
```

Output:

```
sensorId=1 40.125
sensorId=2 -0.062
```

Edit: Tested with gawk 5.0.0, 2 different gawk 4.2.1's, gawk 4.1.4, gawk 4.0.2, mawk 1.9.9.6, mawk 1.3.3, awk version 20121220 and Busybox awk.